# How to persist _layout state between pages in Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a variable `checked` in my __layout.svelte and I want to have the value remain unchanged between page navigations. Instead when I navigate to a new page `checked` gets reset back to the default, false. Is there a way to simply persist layout or app state between page loads?

The context for the question is that I need to maintain the value of checked, which is a manual dark mode switch, across page navigations in the app.

```
<!-- __layout.svelte -->
<script>

  let checked = false

  $: checked, console.log('checked is', checked)

</script>

<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about">About</a>
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>

<div style="margin-top:2em">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" bind:checked/>
    a checkbox...
  </label>
</div>

<slot></slot>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a good example for Svelte Store. ([Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store))

Best practice is to create a file containing your stored variables. In this case i called the file `store.js` inside the `lib` folder.

[image]

`store.js`:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const checked = writable(false); // set the default value to false
```

Anywhere in your project you can now import this store with the following line in the `<script/>` tag:

```
import {checked} from '$lib/store.js';
```

You can also bind this store to a checkbox like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={$checked}/>
```

This could be your `index.svelte` file which will automatically update the `<h1/>` tag:

```
<script>
  import {checked} from '$lib/store.js';
</script>

<h1>{$checked}</h1>
```

Svelte Store offer many more features (subscribing, derived or readable stores,...). Therefore i linked the ([Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store)) above.

---

EDIT: Extending this concept by using the browsers `localStorage` allows us to save the data across browser sessions ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)).

The example below:

1. Subscribes to the Svelte writable
2. Checks `if (browser)` - due to SSR, the server would throw an error, since it doesn't have a `localStorage`
3. Uses the JSON parser, because the localStorage only saves `Strings` and not `Booleans`

Updated `store.js` file:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import { browser } from "$app/env";

export const checked = writable();

if (browser){
    checked.set(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checked")) || false);
    checked.subscribe(value => {
        localStorage.setItem("checked", JSON.stringify(value));
    });
}
```

Comment: A store alone probably will not be enough to persist data, in case of a full page load or reload. But serializing the store into/from `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` would do the trick.

Comment: Tested and works as needed. I've updated the question to specify that state only needs to be maintained across page navigation in the app. As indicated by @Thomas, a page refresh goes back to the initial value, and so state needs to be persisted by other means.

Comment: @IanEngelbrecht I updated my answer to save the state across sessions by using the localStorage.

Comment: So if this is just an object that holds data how does it work with static site generation?

Comment: @ZayX to what exactly are you referring to? Where are your doubts?

Comment: @miwin When I do static site generation I will have seperate pages. How does the object persists between different pages?

Comment: @ZayX that is the entire purpose of stores! To communicate between different components and pages. All of this happens on the client side. If you want to know how it works under the hood, please look into the Svelte source code.

Comment: @miwin thank you for your answer. I will assume that even when I do SSG svelte takes on routing and repopulating the page with framework internals. This should be the thing than enables js object to be preserved. I will definetly check source code when I have time.